# how to logon to session after logout in qucikfix contains multiple sessions?

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, quickfixn

Below attached config file

```
    [default]
PersistMessages=Y
ConnectionType=initiator
UseDataDictionary=Y

[SESSION] 
ConnectionType=initiator
FileStorePath=store 
FileLogPath=fixlog 
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
AppDataDictionary=FIX50SP2.xml 
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT.1.1.xml
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SenderCompID=xxxxx
TargetCompID=yyyyy
DeliverToCompID=zzzzz
Username=xxxxxx
Password=yyyyyy
SocketConnectHost=aaaa
SocketConnectPort=xxxxx
HeartBtInt=20
#ReconnectInterval=30 
ResetOnLogon=Y
#ResetOnLogout=Y 
#ResetOnDisconnect=Y

[SESSION] 
ConnectionType=initiator
FileStorePath=store 
FileLogPath=fixlog 
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
AppDataDictionary=FIX50SP2.xml 
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT.1.1.xml
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SenderCompID=aaaaa
TargetCompID=bbbb
Username=xxxxx
Password=cccccc
DeliverToCompID=yyyyy
SocketConnectHost=xxxxx
SocketConnectPort=dddddd
HeartBtInt=20
#ReconnectInterval=30 
ResetOnLogon=Y
```

TO logout one session i'm sending

`QuickFix.Session.LookupSession(priceSessionID).Logout();`

i received logout for the particular session.
Here my question is,
how to logon to the same session without logging out another session??
and with out stopping the initiator.

Comment: What don't you want to stop the initiator?

Comment: You can't simply log in the session once you've received the logout?

Answer (score 0):

QF is not really intended for usage where you are manually logging on or logging out.

The intended workflow is:

1. Start your app at any time.
2. If the current time is within the configured session window, attempt login
3. If the current time is NOT within the configured session window, wait until the session start-time and then attempt login
4. When session end-time occurs, logoff.

Comment: I think you can with initiator.stop/start, but you said you don't want to do that, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: if i stop initiator both the sessions will logout...i don't want that to happen i want to logout only one session...and want to login to that particular session after logout

Comment: Probably some administrative workflows require manual logout/logins? Maybe not desirable, but yeah...